# Compare Seq and Array different behavior

Tags: scala, equality, scala-collections

Scala seems to view `Seq`s with same values as a single object, but not the same as `Array`s.

`Seq` behaves the same as `List`, `Set`.

```
scala> Array(1) == Array(1)
res2: Boolean = false

scala> Seq(1) == Seq(1)
res3: Boolean = true
```

Why does it happen? What's the reason behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Array is essentially an alias for Java’s array, which implements equals as reference equality - only returning true if two variables point to the same array instance.

Array is the only Scala collection for which `==` checks for reference equality, for all others it delegates to .equals which checks for value equality.

Though, Scala 2.13 introduces immutable Arrays which behave as expected.

For now, you can use `.sameElements` or `.deep` to compare instead.